# Postgres throws error while inserting datetime with timezone

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, pytz

I have a postgres table where I have a column `date` of type **timestamp with time zone**

Now when I insert a record into the table, it always fails for this column and gives an error like

```
column "date" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type numeric
```

I am using python to do a sql query and for the column date, I pass the value **datetime.now(tz)** which I basically obtain by

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
date = datetime.now(tz)
```

In the table there are already existing values for the column `date` which has values like `2018-07-23 10:30:00+05:30` and my generated value is `2018-10-04 17:53:18.431857+05:30` which I believe is in the same format.Then why am I receiving this error?

Comment: try to type cast it with ::date

Comment: @BhartiMohane can you post an example?

Comment: Just FYI, timestamp with timezone is literally no different than timestamp-- except that data is stored as UTC in the table and told to translate to/from the clients set timezone upon select/insert/update. The timezone is not stored in the system, nor needed when inserting IE:+5:30 is unnecessary. Just cast the string to a timestamp and you're good to go.